# Storing a voice in User Defaults - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults, voice, speechsynthesizer

I want to store a voice in the User Defaults. Since we can't store directly a voice, what's the best way for storing it? Using the index in the array `[NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices]` can differ after installing a new voice. And what about converting to an `NSData` or storing using its identifier?

Comment: is there a reason you can't store the name of the voice?

Comment: No, I'm just asking the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, an index is a really bad idea.  I use `[[NSSpeechSynthesizer attributesForVoice: voice] objectForKey: NSVoiceName]`.